# Why "could not write licensing information" with SQL Server, SSIS in Docker build?

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu, ssis

I'm trying to build a Docker image with SQL Server and SSIS.

I created a Dockerfile using a template from a response at [SSISDB/SSIS in docker linux containers? #213](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/213).

I updated the code with [Microsoft's instructions for installing SSIS on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ssis?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu).

The `FROM` instruction refers to [Microsoft's Ubuntu-based Docker image](https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/mssql/server/about) for SQL Server 2022.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
RUN add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022.list)"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mssql-server-is

RUN SSIS_PID=Developer ACCEPT_EULA=Y /opt/ssis/bin/ssis-conf -n setup

RUN mkdir -p /home/mssql/.ssis/.system

RUN chmod -R 777 /home/mssql

RUN cp /root/.bashrc /home/mssql/.bashrc

RUN echo "\nexport PATH=/opt/ssis/bin:$PATH" > /home/mssql/.bashrc

USER mssql
```

When I run it, though, I get an error saying 'Could not write licensing information':

```
 => ERROR [ 7/11] RUN SSIS_PID=Developer ACCEPT_EULA=Y /opt/ssis/bin/ssis-conf -n setup                                                                    0.4s
------
 > [ 7/11] RUN SSIS_PID=Developer ACCEPT_EULA=Y /opt/ssis/bin/ssis-conf -n setup:
0.390 Could not write licensing information.
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  13 |     RUN apt-get install -y mssql-server-is
  14 |     
  15 | >>> RUN SSIS_PID=Developer ACCEPT_EULA=Y /opt/ssis/bin/ssis-conf -n setup
  16 |     
  17 |     RUN mkdir -p /home/mssql/.ssis/.system
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c SSIS_PID=Developer ACCEPT_EULA=Y /opt/ssis/bin/ssis-conf -n setup" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

My searches have found nothing related to this error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this was related to my using an M<n> Mac while trying to set up a Linux/AMD64 image.

In Docker Desktop, under the settings (gear in upper right):

- On 'General' tab, ensure `Use Virtualization framework` is selected.
- On 'Features in development' tab, select `Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon`.

I still had further errors after doing this, but it least it moved me forward.

---

*Note*: what I'm doing here is "experimental" as there is no "official" way to run SQL Server and SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) on ARM at this time (or in the foreseeable future). However, I didn't find this error specifically for anyone else giving it a go, so I posted the question.